# run ssh script into ubuntu instance do something, when exit, stay in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am running a very simple script that will ssh into a remote ubuntu instance, move around the directory structure execute a few things, then I want the prompt to stay in Ubuntu.  When the script ends, in ends back at the local prompt.  How do I make modify the script so that it finishes with the remote prompt?

```
local$ ssh -i xxx.pem ubuntu@xxx.ap-region.compute.amazonaws.com \
          "cd virtualenv; ls -lh;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things needed to be added to your commandline:

- The `bash` command in the end starts the `bash` shell (you can start any other you want)
- The `-t` switch will make sure the remote server will allocate you TTY and your shell will work as expected:

---

```
local$ ssh -t -i xxx.pem ubuntu@xxx.ap-region.compute.amazonaws.com \
      "cd virtualenv; ls -lh; bash"
```

Comment: What if i want to run a bash shell command.  in this instance its "source" to execute a python virtual environment. I tried "cd virtualenv; source bin/activate; ls -lh; bash"  But this hasn't worked.

Comment: What-if is a new question. Please fill a new one about python.